# Overlapping of text in table

Tags: tables

I have created a table in LaTeX. But text from two different rows is being overlapped. I tried with manipulating row height, but problem persists. Kindly help. ***[image: **Screen shot of output is attached.**]*** Code is pasted here.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sl.\\ No.\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Filter \&\\  Parameters\end{tabular}                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Window\\ Size\end{tabular} & SSI                        & ENL                         & SMPI                        & SSIM                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lee \\ (Noise\\ Variance=0.25)\end{tabular}}                                 & $3\times3$                                            & 0.711                      & 13.402                      & 46.151                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $5\times5$                                            & 0.650                      & 16.031                      & 42.696                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $7\times7$                                            & 0.624                      & 17.364                      & 41.050                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frost\\ ($k=1$)\end{tabular}}                                                & $3\times 3$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.616} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17.814} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{38.340} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.540} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23.240} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31.953} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.506} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{26.493} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28.350} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frost\\ ($k=2$)\end{tabular}}                                                & $3\times 3$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.618} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17.703} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{38.203} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.543} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22.935} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31.993} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{9}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.511} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{25.911} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28.468} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\ \hline
10                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frost\\ ($k=0.5$)\end{tabular}}                                              & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.616                      & 17.863                      & 38.403                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
11                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.538                      & 23.370                      & 31.944                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
12                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.503                      & 26.758                      & 28.305                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
13                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Lee\\ ($k=1$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$,\\  $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}     & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.613                      & 18.004                      & 39.158                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
14                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times5$                                            & 0.528                      & 24.301                      & 34.316                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
15                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.484                      & 28.959                      & 31.464                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
16                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Lee\\ ($k=2$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$, \\ $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}     & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.621                      & 17.584                      & 38.570                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
17                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.538                      & 23.350                      & 34.651                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
18                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.497                      & 27.395                      & 32.071                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
19                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Lee\\ ($k=0.5$, \\ $C_v$=0.2615, \\ $C_max$=1.2247)\end{tabular}}   & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.610                      & 18.202                      & 39.583                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
20                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.523                      & 24.731                      & 34.269                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
21                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times7$                                            & 0.478                      & 29.689                      & 31.286                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
22                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Frost\\ ($k=1$, \\ $C_v=0.2615,$\\  $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}   & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.616                      & 17.846                      & 38.206                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
23                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.540                      & 23.239                      & 31.829                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
24                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.506                      & 26.471                      & 28.198                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
25                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Frost\\ ($k=2$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$, \\ $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}   & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.617                      & 17.762                      & 37.913                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
26                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.543                      & 22.972                      & 31.721                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
27                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.511                      & 25.909                      & 28.184                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
28                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Frost\\ ($k=0.5$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$, \\ $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}} & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.615                      & 17.880                      & 38.345                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
29                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.538                      & 23.352                      & 31.897                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
30                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.503                      & 26.717                      & 28.244                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
31                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{GammaMap}                                                                                               & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.608                      & 18.319                      & 40.178                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
32                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.521                      & 24.903                      & 34.421                      & 1.00                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
33                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.475                      & 29.945                      & 31.384                      & 1.00                      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: it seem that your `multirow` contents is taller sum of height of the spanned rows. there is not much can be done: (i) increase vertical spaces by changing `\arraystreatch` or (ii) make `multirow` cell wider that their contents will have less lines. for concrete help please extend your code snipped to complete small document with your table.

Comment: Why not use r for the first column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't widen the text-width (so you can avoid the 4-line subtables that are causing the problem), you can increase the vertical spacing after each line by adding some extra space to each row. Just append `[..]` to each `\\` at the end of the table rows, where `..` is any length (e.g., `1ex`). In the code below I defined `\extra` as a `\newlength` to make it easy to adjust. Too small and the rows still overlap. Too big and you run out of room on the page. The image uses `\extra` equal to `.8ex`.[image]

I would strongly consider breaking the table into two tables and increase the spacing a bit; it still looks cramped to me.

Here is the code with [\extra] appended to each row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\newlength{\extra}
\setlength{\extra}{.8ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sl.\\ No.\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Filter \&\\  Parameters\end{tabular}                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Window\\ Size\end{tabular} & SSI                        & ENL                         & SMPI                        & SSIM                      \\[\extra] \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lee \\ (Noise\\ Variance=0.25)\end{tabular}}                                 & $3\times3$                                            & 0.711                      & 13.402                      & 46.151                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $5\times5$                                            & 0.650                      & 16.031                      & 42.696                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $7\times7$                                            & 0.624                      & 17.364                      & 41.050                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frost\\ ($k=1$)\end{tabular}}                                                & $3\times 3$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.616} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17.814} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{38.340} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.540} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23.240} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31.953} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.506} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{26.493} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28.350} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\[\extra] \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frost\\ ($k=2$)\end{tabular}}                                                & $3\times 3$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.618} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17.703} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{38.203} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.543} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22.935} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31.993} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{9}                                                 &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.511} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{25.911} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28.468} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} \\[\extra] \hline
10                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Frost\\ ($k=0.5$)\end{tabular}}                                              & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.616                      & 17.863                      & 38.403                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
11                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.538                      & 23.370                      & 31.944                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
12                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.503                      & 26.758                      & 28.305                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
13                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Lee\\ ($k=1$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$,\\  $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}     & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.613                      & 18.004                      & 39.158                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
14                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times5$                                            & 0.528                      & 24.301                      & 34.316                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
15                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.484                      & 28.959                      & 31.464                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
16                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Lee\\ ($k=2$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$, \\ $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}     & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.621                      & 17.584                      & 38.570                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
17                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.538                      & 23.350                      & 34.651                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
18                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.497                      & 27.395                      & 32.071                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
19                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Lee\\ ($k=0.5$, \\ $C_v$=0.2615, \\ $C_max$=1.2247)\end{tabular}}   & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.610                      & 18.202                      & 39.583                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
20                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.523                      & 24.731                      & 34.269                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
21                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times7$                                            & 0.478                      & 29.689                      & 31.286                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
22                                                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Frost\\ ($k=1$, \\ $C_v=0.2615,$\\  $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}   & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.616                      & 17.846                      & 38.206                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
23                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.540                      & 23.239                      & 31.829                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
24                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.506                      & 26.471                      & 28.198                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
25                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Frost\\ ($k=2$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$, \\ $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}}   & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.617                      & 17.762                      & 37.913                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
26                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.543                      & 22.972                      & 31.721                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
27                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.511                      & 25.909                      & 28.184                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
28                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enhanced Frost\\ ($k=0.5$, \\ $C_v=0.2615$, \\ $C_max=1.2247$)\end{tabular}} & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.615                      & 17.880                      & 38.345                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
29                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.538                      & 23.352                      & 31.897                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
30                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.503                      & 26.717                      & 28.244                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
31                                                                      & \multirow{3}{*}{GammaMap}                                                                                               & $3\times 3$                                           & 0.608                      & 18.319                      & 40.178                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
32                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $5\times 5$                                           & 0.521                      & 24.903                      & 34.421                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
33                                                                      &                                                                                                                         & $7\times 7$                                           & 0.475                      & 29.945                      & 31.384                      & 1.00                      \\[\extra] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would select different way in your table design:

- it seems that your table is generated by some table generator or you use `multicolumn` anywhere ... all of them are superfluous
- employ package by which i can simplify table code: `\thead` from package `\makecell` can replace all nested `tabular` in columns' headers
- remove all vertical lines
- instead `\hline` use rules defined in package `booktabs`. by this a "professional" looks of table is achieved
- remove all `\cline{...}
- for columns with numbers use column type `S` defined in package `siunitx`
- column with math expression define as math environment (`>{$}c<{$}`) and remove all `$` in this column

beside this, since you not provide any information about your document:

- i use package `geometry` to determine page layout
- for table environment select `tabularx`
- for `multirow` exploit possibilities defined in its recent version:
  `\multirow[t]{3}{=}{...}`, which overtake column formatting. for this column i select column type `X`, so the contents of `multirow` cells automatically break into more lines, if necessary

result of this approach is:

[image]

*mwe*:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            S[table-format=2.1]
            X
        >{$}c<{$}
            S[table-format=1.3]
       *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]}
            S[table-format=1.2]
                                }
    \toprule
{\thead{Sl.\\ No.}}
    & \thead{Filter \&\\  Parameters}
        & \thead{\text{Window}\\ \text{Size}}
                    & {SSI} & {ENL}     & {SMPI}    & {SSIM}    \\
    \midrule
1   & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Lee  ($\text{Noise Variance}=0.25$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.711 & 13.402    & 46.151    & 1.00      \\
2   &   & 5\times5  & 0.650 & 16.031    & 42.696    & 1.00      \\
3   &   & 7\times7  & 0.624 & 17.364    & 41.050    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
4   & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Frost ($k=1$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.616 & 17.814    & 38.340    & 1.00      \\
5   &   & 5\times5  & 0.540 & 23.240    & 31.953    & 1.00      \\
6   &   & 7\times7  & 0.506 & 26.493    & 28.350    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
7   & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Frost ($k=2$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.618 & 17.703    & 38.203    & 1.00      \\
8   &   & 5\times5  & 0.543 & 22.935    & 31.993    & 1.00      \\
9   &   & 7\times7  & 0.511 & 25.911    & 28.468    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
10  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Frost ($k=0.5$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.616 & 17.863    & 38.403    & 1.00      \\
11  &   & 5\times5  & 0.538 & 23.370    & 31.944    & 1.00      \\
12  &   & 7\times7  & 0.503 & 26.758    & 28.305    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
13  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Enhanced Lee ($k=1$, $C_v=0.2615$, $C_{\max}=1.2247$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.613 & 18.004    & 39.158    & 1.00      \\
14  &   & 5\times5  & 0.528 & 24.301    & 34.316    & 1.00      \\
15  &   & 7\times7  & 0.484 & 28.959    & 31.464    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
16  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Enhanced Lee ($k=2$, $C_v=0.2615$, $C_{\max}=1.2247$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.621 & 17.584    & 38.570    & 1.00      \\
17  &   & 5\times5  & 0.538 & 23.350    & 34.651    & 1.00      \\
18  &   & 7\times7  & 0.497 & 27.395    & 32.071    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
19  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Enhanced Lee ($k=0.5$, $C_v=0.2615$, $C_{\max}=1.2247$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.610 & 18.202    & 39.583    & 1.00      \\
20  &   & 5\times5  & 0.523 & 24.731    & 34.269    & 1.00      \\
21  &   & 7\times7  & 0.478 & 29.689    & 31.286    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
22  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Enhanced Frost ($k=1$, $C_v=0.2615$,  $C_{\max}=1.2247$)}
        & 3\times3  & 0.616 & 17.846    & 38.206    & 1.00      \\
23  &   & 5\times5  & 0.540 & 23.239    & 31.829    & 1.00      \\
24  &   & 7\times7  & 0.506 & 26.471    & 28.198    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
25  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Enhanced Frost ($k=2$,  $C_v=0.2615$, $C_{\max}=1.2247$)}
        & 3\times3 & 0.617  & 17.762    & 37.913    & 1.00      \\
26  &   & 5\times5 & 0.543  & 22.972    & 31.721    & 1.00      \\
27  &   & 7\times7 & 0.511  & 25.909    & 28.184    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
28  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Enhanced Frost ($k=0.5$, C_v=0.2615$, $C_{\max}=1.2247$)}
        & 3\times3 & 0.615  & 17.880    & 38.345    & 1.00      \\
29  &   & 5\times5  & 0.538 & 23.352    & 31.897    & 1.00      \\
30  &   & 7\times7  & 0.503 & 26.717    & 28.244    & 1.00      \\
    \midrule
31  & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{GammaMap}
        & 3\times 3 & 0.608     & 18.319    & 40.178    & 1.00      \\
32  &   & 5\times5  & 0.521     & 24.903    & 34.421    & 1.00      \\
33  &   & 7\times7  & 0.475     & 29.945    & 31.384    & 1.00      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```